# Best way to load markers from Firestore

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, google-maps-markers

I know that this question is duplicate, but i had a problem finding the best solution for the specific use of Firebase Firestore as a database.

**Here is the problem:**

I have a lot of markers in my Firestore Database and I would like to load only markers near me.

One solution could be load all markers and set visibility to `false` if they are out the `LatLngBounds`, but this is not the case.

**Why?**

You will always request all markers from your database and this is very useless specially if you have a tons of markers and you only need to load a few of them.

*I asked this question to help users deal with this problem. Below you can find the solution.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HERE IS THE SOLUTION THAT I USED**

I made a `query` on my Firestore Database and create a Box around my position.

```
FirebaseFirestore database = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

CollectionReference locals = database.collection("locals");
//I created a box with user LatLng. Every marker inside this box will be loaded
Query markers = locals.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("location", new GeoPoint(userLat - 0.5, userLng - 0.5))
.whereLessThanOrEqualTo("location", new GeoPoint(userLat + 0.5, userLng + 0.5));

    markers.get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()){ 

                            String localName = (String) document.get("localName");
                            GeoPoint location = (GeoPoint) document.get("location");
                            LatLng localPosition = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
                            Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                    .position(localPosition)
                                    .title(localName)
                                    );
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

**Here is an example:**
[image]

Your request will load only markers inside this box.

**Why this is very important?**

If you have 5000 markers in your database and you have 10.000 daily users, every time a user opens the map he will request 5000 documents to your database. If 10.000 people open the map once a day there will be 50.000.000 requests to documents. 
If you have a Blaze plan this will cost you $29.10 daily.

Try to imagine if you have 100.000 users... there will be $299.10 daily.

With my solution you load only documents in a specific area that you can define increasing or decreasing the box.

Hope I helped many users. if someone has a better solution, I'm ready to listen.

Comment: Hi Matteo - this is awesome! Can I ask you, how do you implement it without the box? If I just want all the markers. I dont have a userLat and userLng, which is giving me the problems. In my collection, I have a document with a GeoPoint containing two numbers/coordinates..

Comment: @badaboomskey replace `markers.get()` to `locals.get()`